# How to get the 3D views of a Revit file on Forge

Tags: autodesk-forge, revit

If a revit file is already published on BIM 360 docs, is there an easy way to query the name/element_id of it's views through Forge?

I have a Forge plugin that's connected to my BIM 360 account and I can query the hubs and the projects. I can also download the Revit projects. However, it seems like I have to do some translation to SVF according this tutorial:
https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/tutorials/xtract-metadata/about-this-tutorial/
Given that the Revit files are already published on BIM 360, is there a direct API I can use to query the view name/ids?

Answer (score 1):

Before building application on BIM, you need to have [access to BIM APIs](https://fieldofviewblog.wordpress.com/2017/08/18/no-custom-integrations-tab/comment-page-1/), after that, it takes multiple api calls, getting the hubid, projectid, folderid, file and the version id and subsequently view it on forge viewer.

Here's the [official tutorial](https://learnforge.autodesk.io/#/tutorials/viewhubmodels) for the entire process.

Comment: Hi Varun, thanks for the answer. I added some detail to the question.

Comment: When a file is uploaded in BIM, translation to svf happens automatically. manual translation is required if you upload file to forge bucket, which is not your case. So you can view the file in forge viewer directly without any translation.

Comment: How can I acquire the URN to the manifest without starting a translation job? Should I just go ahead and start a translation job and it will return immediately because it's cached? I am looking at this tutorial: https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/tutorials/xtract-metadata/task3-translate-source-file/

Comment: [In this API](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/reference/http/projects-project_id-items-item_id-versions-GET/) versionid is the urn. Please do the tutorial mentioned in the answer, it won't take much time, it's all ready made code with explanation.

Comment: If you have anymore doubt, please ask. if the information provided was useful, please accept the answer.